# M1 Apple Silicon MongoDB connection creates new database, also affects Docker deploy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, apple-m1

I got a brand new MBP M1 Max last week, started porting over my development environment.  Almost everything as far as nodejs and our projects ported, however, I did run into an issue with Docker.  It turned out that I needed to tell Docker to compile in a linux environment and that resolved issues with BCRYPT.

What I was unaware of was that apparently, that deploy (to QA), did not have a good database connection.  It turns out, that build connects to the server, but then creates a database named "test" and then is apparently using that database rather than the one specified in the URL.

To debug, I took the url from QA and plugged it into development and I am getting the same behavior.

On my old intel mac, I did full pulls and npm installs to get everything to match, and guess what, it works. So everything that was working on Thursday on Intel Mac works with the library updates and code updates since Thursday on the Intel Mac, but the M1 Mac... it doesn't fail, it just creates a whole new database!  By the way, the docker deploys to QA also work on the intel mac.  Something about the M1 Mac is causing this issue.

This does not even make sense to be a bug that one could experience due to a chip change.

Here is our QA DB URL minus information that would make our db public.  It is hosted on MongDB Atlas. Anyone else seeing this behavior as well?  Anyone got the work around?

login: mongodb+srv://fake:password@cluster0.something.mongodb.net/databasenameqa?replicaSet=atlas-12hyiw-shard-0&readPreference=primary&connectTimeoutMS=10000&authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1

I am going to take this over to the git for mongo on node.  Also, I just checked my localhost connection url and it looks like this:

mongodb://localhost:27017/databasenamedev

therefore its not the database name after the / that is the issue.

Comment: it appears if I remove the query portion of the url, the question mark and everything after, the connection attaches to the correct database.  I think Heroku gave me the URL.

Comment: It appears this parameter: authSource=admin  is causing the issue. That appears to be the default, we are removing default url params from the env variable on the server now.